# Ionic 3 - adding ion-segment dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I am facing problem on adding the ion-segment values dynamically..
below are my work around..

TS file:

```
this.rioTypes = ['ABC', 'XYZ', 'PQR'];
  items1: any = [1, 2, 3, 4];
segmentVal: string = "ABC";
```

HTML:

```
<ion-segment [(ngModel)]="segmentVal" color="primary">
  <ion-segment-button *ngFor="let rioType of rioTypes; let i = index;" value="{{rioType}}">
    {{rioType.title}}
  </ion-segment-button>
</ion-segment>

<div [ngSwitch]="segmentVal" *ngFor="let r of rioTypes">

<ion-list *ngSwitchCase="r" ngSelected="selected">

   <ion-item  *ngFor="let item of items1">
    <h2>TAB - {{item}}</h2>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Seems like everything looks fine but when i run in the device.. ony segments are displaying not below contents..
Im using Ionic v3.19.0
Please anybody help me to get it solve.

following error for below code

```
<div [ngSwitch]="segmentVal">

<ion-list *ngFor="let r of rioTypes" *ngSwitchCase="r" 
ngSelected="selected">

 <ion-item  *ngFor="let item of items1">
<h2>TAB - {{item}}</h2>
</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

`Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't have multiple template bindings on one element. Use only one attribute named 'template' or prefixed with * ("

```
    <ion-list *ngSwitchCase="r" [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let r of rioTypes" ngSelected="selected">

       <ion-item  *ngFor="let item of "): ng:///AppModule/UserdashboardPage.html@29:36
at syntaxError (vendor.js:80395)
at TemplateParser.parse (vendor.js:104243)
at JitCompiler._parseTemplate (vendor.js:113630)
at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (vendor.js:113605)
at vendor.js:113507
at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
at JitCompiler._compileComponents (vendor.js:113507)
at vendor.js:113377
at Object.then (vendor.js:80384)
at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (vendor.js:113376)`
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have ended up creating multiple `ngSwitch` blocks with your for loop. You need only one block with all the cases.

Use the loop for your list inside the switch. You can use `ng-container` or a plain div for the loop since you cannot have 2 directives in one tag.

```
<div [ngSwitch]="segmentVal">
<ng-container *ngFor="let r of rioTypes" >
<ion-list *ngSwitchCase="r">

   <ion-item  *ngFor="let item of items1">
    <h2>TAB - {{item}}</h2>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
</ng-container>
</div>
```

Comment: please I have updated question.. I have tried this but getting error  Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Can't have multiple template bindings on one element. Use only one attribute named 'template' or prefixed with * ("

    <ion-list *ngSwitchCase="r" [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let r of rioTypes" ngSelected="selected">

Comment: Not working.. Nothing is displyaing with ng-container..   <div ng-reflect-ng-switch="abc">
    <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "ABC,XYZ,PQR"
}--><!---->
      <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "ABC"
}-->
    <!---->
      <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "XYZ"
}-->
    <!---->
      <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "PQR"
}-->
    
  </div> this is the content

Comment: Also `ngSelected` is not available in angular 2+.. remove it.Which is the default one you want? is `selected` a variable?

Comment: tabs are not changing.. after run first tab content will display and if click on second tab then it wont display.. it does not get activate only.. I have removed ngselected.. I need first tab should be active after page launch

Comment: what is `selected`?

Comment: No.. its not a variable.. I have just added it for selecting first tab

Comment: remove it.. and try

Comment: Hmm removed and tried actually.. tabs are not changing.. after run first tab content will display and if click on second tab then it wont display.. it does not get activate only.. I have removed ngselected..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159884/discussion-between-suraj-rao-and-mallikarjun-hampannavar).